# How to resolve "unrecognized request" error from CVS using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I am using Eclipse Indigo to log into a CVS server. When I try to synchronize with the repository, I am getting this error:

> Problems reported while synchronizing CVS Workspace. 0 of 1 resources
>   were synchronized. The server reported an error: unrecognized request
>   `dated Template Copy-file Mod-time Set-static-directory
>   Update-existing Clear-static-directory Set-sticky New-entry MT
>   Notified Created Remove-entry Checked-in Merged Removed Valid-requests
>   Clear-sticky Module-expansion'

I am able to commit changes, but I cannot see any updates. Does anyone know what this error message means and how to resolve it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this it might solve your problem

> Had the same problem, and solved it when i deleted the content of my workspace/project/WebContent/folder with problem/CVS/Entries, then i refreshed my files in eclipse and it worked. 
>   I guess something there was corrupted.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856686/how-to-solve-synchronizing-cvs-problem-in-eclipse-ide/19716806#19716806).